# How to check string is containing a word and isn't containing another word?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
$str = "this is a test";
```

I want to validate `$str` and return *true* if string is containing `is` and it isn't containing `test`. How can I do that?

---

**Examples:**

```
"this is a test"   // false
"this is a tes"    // true    "is" exists and "test" doesn't exist
"this iss a tes"   // false
"this iss a test"  // false
```

---

Here is my pattern `\bis\b(?!test)`. But it seems to just checks *existing*, I mean it also returns *true* when `test` exists. I mean the result of following code us *true* which shouldn't be *(because `test` exists)*.

```
if (preg_match ("/\bis\b(?!test)/","this is a test")) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

**Note:**  I'm really insist on doing that by regex.

Comment: Downvoter please leave a comment and explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
^                       # anchor it to the beginning of the line
    (?:(?!\btest\b).)*  # makes sure no test can be matched
    \bis\b              # match is as a word
    (?:(?!\btest\b).)*  # same construct as above
$                       # anchor it to the end of the line
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uS8kA1/3).

For a `PHP` code, see the following snippet:

```php
<?php
$string = "this is a test
this is a tes
this iss a tes
this iss a test
this test is";

$regex = '~
            ^                       # anchor it to the beginning of the line
                (?:(?!\btest\b).)*  # makes sure no test can be matched
                \bis\b              # match is as a word
                (?:(?!\btest\b).)*  # same construct as above
            $                       # anchor it to the end of the line
          ~mx';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

***Hint:*** Note that I have changed the answer after it has been accepted to correct flaws in the original answer).

Answer (score 3):

use strpos

```
$str = "this is a test";
if (strpos($str, 'is') !== false && strpos($str, 'test') === false ) {
   return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Also your solution doesn't support word boundary now ..!

Answer (score 2):

Try using lookahed, both positive and negative:

```
^(?=.*\bis\b)(?!.*\btest\b).*
```

Explaining:

```
^              # stands for start of the string, both lookahed below will use it as anchor

(?=            # positive lookahed
    .*         # can have any amount of characters till
    \bis\b     # literal text "is" with boundaries
)              # if not succeed will fail the regex

(?!            # negative lookahead
    .*         # can have any amount of characters till
    \btest\b   # literal text "test" with boundaries
)              # if succeed will fail the regex

.*             # if the regex didn't fail till here, match all characters in this line
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @Shafizadeh. My bad, I typed `=` twice, I've updated

Answer (score 1):

Something like `^(?!.*\btest\b).*\bis\b.*$` so would be:

```
if (preg_match ("(^(?!.*\btest\b).*\bis\b.*$)","this is a test")) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Ok so explanation then, although its obvious, it first checks 'test' doesnt exist with any number of characters before it and then makes sure 'is' does exist.

Comment: Why should the OP try "something like this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This one is pretty close to what I'm looking for .. thx +1 .. Just please apply `\b` on your pattern.

Comment: Ah yes sorry I missed that bit @Shafizadeh. Now added. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this
^.*?\bis\b(?:(?!\btest\b).)*$

Comment: Actually I'm trying to do that by one integrated pattern .. also please add `!` in the beginning of your second condition: `&& !preg_match('/test/',$a)`

Comment: You can wrap text with backticks to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it work proper by regular expression

```
 $str = "this is a test";

     if (preg_match ("/is/",$str) && !preg_match ("/test/",$str)) {
      return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```